# WPF ClickOnce - Publish Location information

Tags: wpf, clickonce, publish

I was wondering where in a VS (2015) project the information under Project > Properties > Publish was kept? On a Web application there was a publish file that contained all the information but I cannot see where this is now kept when doing a ClickOnce WPF application.

I am looking for a means to automate publications to different servers(with different Publish Locations) but cannot see what I would need to update to change where the click once application is published to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe its part of the csproj file. Look for InstallUrl.

Comment: Amazing! Would explain why it wasnt coming up when searching the soluton... I hadnt tried unloading the project to check the vbproj/csproj file.